# Configure swagger in gradle build script with kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, groovy, swagger, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to switch my simple project from Groovy to Kotlin in build scripts.
I'm using this plugin:
https://github.com/gigaSproule/swagger-gradle-plugin
I have this configuration in my build script:

```
swagger{
  apiSource {
    springmvc = false
    locations = ['my.location']
    schemes = ['https']
    host = 'test.com:8080'
    info {
      title = 'My Service'
      version = 'v1'
    }
    swaggerDirectory = "$buildDir/swagger"
  }
```

To where shall I refer to in this situations?
Shall I do something like?

```
    task( "swagger" ) {
      ...
    }
```

It is not quite familiar for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a simple example that we can run, and see the issue you're having?

Comment: I don't have any issues, I just wonder how to configure it in kotlin

Comment: You have to either setup the `pluginManagment` in the settings.gradle or use `configure<ClassOfTheSwaggerConfig> {}`. You can check hello-android sample in the gradle/kotlin-dsl github Repo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is still looking for this information, this is how you would do it using Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
import com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.model.*

plugins {
    id("com.benjaminsproule.swagger") version "1.0.0"
}

swagger {
    apiSource(closureOf<ApiSourceExtension> {
        springmvc = false
        schemes = mutableListOf("https")
        host = "test.com:8080"

        info(closureOf<InfoExtension> {
            title = "My Service"
            version = "v1"
            description = "My Service Description"
            termsOfService = "http://www.example.com/termsOfService"
            contact(closureOf<ContactExtension> {
                email = "email@internet.com"
                name = "A Developer"
                url = "http://www.internet.com"
            })
            license(closureOf<LicenseExtension> {
                url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
                name = "Apache 2.0"
            })
        })

        locations = mutableListOf("com.foo.fighting")
        swaggerDirectory = "$buildDir/swagger"
    })
}
```

I've tested it using [Gradle v4.6](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html).